# berkeley db : how can I delete multi key-datas with php 5?

Tags: php, berkeley-db

i am a green hand in handling BDB width php and now i want to do something like this:

```
for($f=1;$f<6;$f++){
   $BDB->del('mykey'.$f);
}
```

`$BDB` is a global function handling all BDB stuff.  I want to clear all key-values with prefix 'mykey' and different numbers subfix. I think using a "for" function is not good here, and I don't know whether there's any "multi del", "multi put", or "multi get" APIs in BDB? If so, how to use them to get my stuff done?

Answer (score -3):

This is Mike Brey, manager of core development for Berkeley DB.  Sorry for the delay in responding.   Generally, we recommend that folks ask questions over on the Berkeley DB forums.  They are located at http://forums.oracle.com/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=246 and you can go into the specific 'child' forum you need.  In the case go into Berkeley DB.  There is a large community of active Berkeley DB application developers there.

BDB offers bulk get/put APIs.  More information is available in our documentation which you can look at here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/frame_main.html

Comment: It would be more helpful for users of BDB and users that fall into similar difficulties if, aditionally of pointing the user to the full documentation, you provided a simple example, so that your answer could be self contained.